# Rails need to make this data model better

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, database-design, data-modeling

I'm trying to create a data model for a rails app.

Basically I have a locations table that contains records for four different locations. I'm trying to create timeslots for each location for every day. For example. Location1 has 5 9am slots, 5 11am slots, etc.

I now need to be able to create arrangements for a location for a given timeslot.

Currently i have this app working, the only problem is that when you save an arrangement, you also have to update a timeslot record with the arrangement id and a record also has to exist for every timeslot for every location for every day.

I know there's got to be a better way to do this.

Here's my current datamodel:

[image]

Here's my current model setup:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :arrangement
    has_many :timeslots
end

class Timeslot < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :location
    has_one :arrangement
end

class Arrangement < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :location
    belongs_to :timeslot
end
```

And here's a snippet from my current create method in the arrangement controller:

```
if @arrangement.save
# update the timslot record with the arrangement id
if @timeslot = Timeslot.update(@arrangement.timeslot_id, :arrangement_id => @arrangement.id)
```

How can i make this data model better?

**EDIT**
Ideally i'm looking for a data model where i do not have to populate a timeslot for every location and every day.

Theoretically i'd like to have a timeslots table that only has all the timeslots for every location so that i don't have to manually populate the timeslots table.

The biggest thing i'm worried about is having to populate the timeslots table for lets say the next 30 years.

Comment: It might be helpful to have a bit more info on how you manage the timeslots then. For example, how do you currently track how many timeslots a location can have, and how do you track which timeslot a `Timeslot` is for?

Comment: will every location have the same timeslots?

Comment: No they all have different. For example location1 has 5 9am slots, 5 11am slots, etc. location2 only has 2 of each.

Comment: okay sorry, didnt realize that at that time, that changes my perspective, but i realize its almost the same as Zaids. Just remember not to put the arrangment_id column in the timeslot table.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are going to suppose to generate some timeslots for every location, than this would partially work:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :timeslots
    has_many :arrangements, :through => :timeslots
end

class Timeslot < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :location
    has_one :arrangement
end

class Arrangement < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :timeslot
end
```

The problem with setting this is that you wont be able to `normally` fetch the arrangments location since you can't make a `belongs_to through` relationship.
But you can basically do the `arrangement.timeslot.user` , instead of having a belongs_to relationship to a `location`, it would be kinda redundant, but you could make it that way also.

You don't need to set up the id at the has_one end of the relation:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_one-association

Comment: My ideal solution would be to not have to generate timeslots for every location for every day. I'd like to just have a timeslots table with a record for each location for each timeslot, that way i wouldn't have to specify the timeslots for x number of years.

Comment: Why don't you try to make it without the `Timeslot` table and just have a `Location` and `Arrangement` table. When a user wants to make a `arrangement`, you give him a dropdown list to choose the time when the `arrangment` is going to be depending on the `location` he choosed. Would that work?

Comment: Because i need to limit each location to a specific number of timeslots. For example location1 has 5 of each, location2 has 2 of each. Also when a timeslot is taken, i do not want to show it in the dropdown list of available timeslots.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need a direct association between `Location` and `Arrangement`? I'd instead consider organising it using a [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association) association, like this:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :timeslots
    has_many :arrangements, through: :timeslots
end

class Timeslot < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :location
    has_one :arrangement
end

class Arrangement < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :timeslot
end
```

If you do it this way, you'd create an `Arrangement` as belonging to a `Timeslot`, so you wouldn't need to manually update that. If you want to get all the `Arrangement`s for a `Location`, you can still do that with `location.arrangements` because you set up the association through the timeslots. And if you need to know the location of an arrangement, you can just use `arrangement.timeslot.location`.

(Note, I'm assuming that each `Location` can actually have multiple `Arrangement`s, and that the `has_one` in your question is a mistake? Let me know if I'm wrong on that front.)

Comment: Yes you are correct each location can have multiple arrangements.

Comment: Cool, that makes more sense :) Ultimately, you may be able to do away with the `Timeslot` model entirely, depending on whether you need to do anything else with it. At the very least, if you don't want to create all of them in advance, you could only create one when you have an arrangement to put in it, and limit the number you could have for any one slot through the `Location` model.

Comment: check out my solution and see if its makes sense to you. Thanks

Comment: @Zippie ? What's the typo? If you're picking on the hash syntax, either is correct (I just tend to use 1.9 style so long as all my keys are symbols).

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't know that :)